# Powershell removes results when creating lists

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

SO when I query AD to get users in groups using `MemberOf` once the user is added to a result the no longer are add to any additional results. For example :

joe.admin is in Domain Admins and Enterprise Admins. When added to the result `$da` it should also be added to `$eadmins` too. Please see the code below.

```ps
###########################################################################
#
# NAME: Ad account auditing
#
###########################################################################


[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName="CurrentForest")] 
param
(   
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Domain",Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $Domain


)
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy/MM/dd
$date1 = Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy
#ipmo activedirectory
$outfile = @()
[int] $InactiveDays = 180

$da=0
$admins=0
$eadmins=0
$sadmins=0
$wsadmins=0
$itadmins=0
$sa=0
$con=0

    # Connect to the specified domain if domain parameter used
    if ($Domain)
    {
        $DomainContext = new-object System.directoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext("Domain",$Domain)
        $ObjDomain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetDomain($DomainContext)
        $PDCEmulators += $ObjDomain.PDCRoleOwner
    }
    elseif($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -match "CurrentForest")
    {
    $domain = [system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
    }








Function Get-NETBiosName ( $dn, $ConfigurationNC )
{
    try
    {
        $Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
        $Searcher.SearchScope = "subtree" 
        $Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("nETBIOSName")| Out-Null
        $Searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://cn=Partitions,$ConfigurationNC"
        $Searcher.Filter = "(nCName=$dn)"
        $NetBIOSName = ($Searcher.FindOne()).Properties.Item("nETBIOSName")
        Return $NetBIOSName
    }
    catch
    {
        Return $null
    }
}
$ADSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$ADSearcher.PageSize = 100000
$ADSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
$UserProperties = @("samaccountname","whenChanged","LastLogontimestamp","CanonicalName","DistinguishedName","MemberOf","Description","mail","whenCreated","isdisabled","lastlogondate","pwdLastSet","GivenName","userAccountControl","accountExpires","ispasswordnotrequired","isPasswordNeverExpires","accountExpirationdate","isCriticalSystemObject","isPreAuthNotRequired")
$ADSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@($UserProperties))

# Connect to the PDC Emulator
                $ObjDeDomain = [ADSI] "LDAP://$($domain)"
                $ADSearcher.SearchRoot = $ObjDeDomain

                # Get the domain NETBIOS name
                $DomainNameString = Get-NETBiosName $objDeDomain.distinguishedName $objRootDSE.configurationNamingContext

                # Collect user accounts
                $getalluser = $ADSearcher.FindAll()





    foreach ($getalluser1 in $getalluser)
    {

$getuser1 = $getalluser1.GetDirectoryEntry()

    [string]$accountExpires = $getuser1.accountExpires
    #[string]$accountExpirationdate = $getuser1.accountExpirationdate
    [string]$userAccountControl = $getuser1.userAccountControl
    [string]$GivenName=$getuser1.GivenName
    [string]$samaccountname= $getuser1.samaccountname
    [string]$whenChanged= $getuser1.whenChanged
    [string]$CanonicalName= $getuser1.CanonicalName
    [string]$DistinguishedName= $getuser1.DistinguishedName
    [string]$MemberOf= $getuser1.MemberOf
    [string]$Description= $getuser1.Description
    [string]$mail= $getuser1.mail
    [string]$whenCreated= $getuser1.whenCreated
    #[string]$PasswordNeverExpires= $getuser1.PasswordNeverExpires


    if($userAccountControl -band 2 )
{
write-host "$samaccountname account is disabled"
[string]$isdisabled="Yes"
}
else
{
[string]$isdisabled="no"
}
    if($userAccountControl -band 8388608 )
{
[string]$ispasswordexpired="Yes"
}
else
{
[string]$ispasswordexpired="no"
}
    if($userAccountControl -band 16 )
{
[string]$islocked="Yes"
}
else
{
[string]$islocked="no"
}
   If($isdisabled -like "*Yes*" -or $islocked -like "*Yes*" -or $ispasswordexpired -like "*Yes*")
    {
    [string]$IsInactive="Yes"
    }
    else
    {
    [string]$IsInactive="No"
    }

    If($MemberOf -like "*Domain Admin*")
    {
    $accountType = "Domain Admins"
$da+=1
    }
    elseIf($MemberOf -like "*Administrators*")
    {
    $accountType = "Administrators"
$admins+=1
    }
    elseIf($MemberOf -like "*Enterprise Admins*" -or $admins -or $da)
    {
    $accountType = "Enterprise Admins"
$eadmins+=1
    }
    elseIf($MemberOf -like "*Schema Admins*")
    {
    $accountType = "Schema Admins"
$sadmins+=1
    }
    elseIf($MemberOf -like "*IT.Support.Staff*")
    {
    $accountType = "IT.Support.Staff"
$itadmins+=1
    }
    elseIf($MemberOf -like "*WSAdmin*")
    {
    $accountType = "WSAdmins"
$wsadmins+=1
    }
    elseIf($Description -like "Built-in*")
    {
    $accountType = "System Accounts"
$sa+=1
    }
    elseIf($MemberOf -like "*Consultant*" -or $MemberOf -like "*Consultants*" -or $DistinguishedName -like "*OU=Consultants*" -or $DistinguishedName -like "*OU=Vendor Accounts*")
    {
    $accountType = "Consultants"
$con+=1
    }
    else
    {
    $accountType = "Non privileged account"
$npa+=1
    }



$object = new-object psobject

$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "ObjectType" -Value $accountType
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "SamAccountName" -Value $samaccountname
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "IsInactive" -Value $IsInactive
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "IsLocked" -Value $islocked
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "IsPasswordExpired" -Value $ispasswordexpired
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "PasswordNeverExpires" -Value $PasswordNeverExpires
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "pwdLastSet" -Value $pwdLastSet
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "UserAccountControl" -Value $userAccountControl
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "GivenName" -Value $GivenName
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "Mail" -Value $mail
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "WhenCreated" -Value $whenCreated
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "Domain" -Value "$domain"
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "WhenChanged" -Value $whenChanged
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "isdisabled" -Value $isdisabled
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "DistinguishedName" -Value $DistinguishedName
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "MemberOf" -Value $memberof
$object | add-member -membertype noteproperty -Name "Description" -Value $Description



$outfile+=$object


$isPreAuthNotRequired=""
$isCriticalSystemObject=""
$passwordnotrequired = ""
    $PasswordNeverExpires = ""
    $accountExpires = ""
    $accountExpirationdate = ""
    $accountExpires = ""
    $userAccountControl = ""
    $GivenName=""
    $lastlogontimestamp1= ""
    $lastlogontimestamp = ""
    $samaccountname= ""
    $whenChanged= ""
    $CanonicalName= ""
    $DistinguishedName= ""
    $MemberOf= ""
    $Description= ""
    $mail= ""
    $whenCreated= ""
    $isdisabled= ""
    $LastLogon= ""
    $pwdLastSet= ""
    $IsInactive=""
    $accountType=""
$getuser1=""
} 


Write-host "Domain Admins = $da"
Write-host "Administrators = $admins"
Write-host "Enterprise Admins = $eadmins"
Write-host "Schema Admins = $sadmins"
Write-host "WSAdmins = $wsadmins"
Write-host "IT.Support.Staff = $itadmins"
Write-host "System Accounts = $SA"
Write-host "Consultants = $con"
Write-host "Non privileged account = $npa"

$da=0
$admins=0
$eadmins=0
$sadmins=0
$wsadmins=0
$itadmins=0
$sa=0
$con=0
$outfile |Export-Csv ".\$domain-AdaccountAudit-$date1.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Rename-Item ".\$domain-AdaccountAudit-$date1.csv" ".\$date1.csv"

Import-Csv ".\$date1.csv" | Group-Object -Property "ObjectType" | 
    Foreach-Object {$path=$_.name+".csv" ; $_.group | 
    Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation}
```

Comment: `if(){}elseif{}` are mutually exclusive - change your `elseif` statements to `if` statements, or use a [`switch` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) instead

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the individual blocks in an `if/elseif/else` group are mutually exclusive (as the `else` suggests).

replace the `elseif` blocks with individual `if` statements:

```
if($MemberOf -like "*Domain Admin*")
{
    $accountType = "Domain Admins"
    $da+=1
}
if($MemberOf -like "*Administrators*")
{
    $accountType = "Administrators"
    $admins+=1
}
# etc...
```

Alternatively, use a `switch`:

```
switch($MemberOf){
    "*Domain Admin*" {
        $accountType = "Domain Admins"
        $da+=1
    }
    "*Administrators*" {
        $accountType = "Administrators"
        $admins+=1
    }
    # etc...
}
```

The `$accountType` variable will be overwritten every time a condition matches, but it's not clear from your script how you want to handle that.